# Trigonometric Functions on a unit circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have to find all solutions for $\theta$ in the given range:
\begin{equation}
tan (\theta) = \frac {-1}{\sqrt3}, -\pi \le \theta  \lt 2\pi
\end{equation}

I said that if $(x,y)$ is on the unit circle we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt3} 
\end{equation}
since $x^2+y^2=1$ $\implies x =  \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$,$y=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x = - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$,$y=\frac{1}{2}$

I am struggling on how to find the angles because I didn't understand the concept. I put my points into the circle but then I get confused about the angles. The one angle it will be $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{6}$ since $tan^{-1}(-\frac{1}{\sqrt3})= - \frac{\pi}{6}$.

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand the way of thinking for the other angles?

With Thanks

Comment: You made an error just above your graph.  You meant $$\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

As you determined,

$$\theta = \arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$$

is one solution.

Remember that the tangent function has period $\pi$.  Thus,

$$\tan\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

when

$$\theta = -\frac{\pi}{6} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.  Since you require that $-\pi \leq \theta < 2\pi$, you can find the remaining solutions in the interval by finding values of $n$ such that

$$-\pi \leq -\frac{\pi}{6} + n\pi < 2\pi$$

Comment: In case we have sin or cos instead of tan?

Comment: For sine, you would find a particular solution $\theta$.  Since $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$, $\pi - \theta$ is another solution.  To find additional solutions, add integer multiples of $2\pi$ to $\theta$ and $\pi - \theta$ to find solutions in the right range.  For cosine, after finding a particular solution $\theta$, you use the fact that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$ to find another solution.  Since cosine also has period $2\pi$, you would add integer multiples of $2\pi$ to $\theta$ and $-\theta$ to find values in the right range.

Comment: For the example with the tan the solutions will be: $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5 \pi}{6} and \frac{11 \pi} {6}$ ?

Comment: That is correct.